# Getting only the length of returned string as result of an SQL query using Derby DB

Tags: sql, derby

I want to test whether a length of a string returned from an SQL query is equal to 3. I'm using DERBY DB.

I've tried something like:

```
ij> select * from tmpuser.friends where length(select distinct ss.schemaname from sys.sysschemas ss fetch next 1 row only)=3;
```

But this query is invalid. I want to show the result of

```
select * from tmpuser.friends
```

only if

```
length(select distinct ss.schemaname from sys.sysschemas ss fetch next 1 row only)=3;
```

is true.

```
ij> select distinct ss.schemaname  from sys.sysschemas ss;
SCHEMANAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
APP
NULLID
SQLJ
SYS
SYSCAT
SYSCS_DIAG
SYSCS_UTIL
SYSFUN
SYSIBM
SYSPROC
SYSSTAT
TMPUSER

12 rows selected
ij> select distinct ss.schemaname  from sys.sysschemas ss fetch next 1 row only;
SCHEMANAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
APP
```

I want to do a test: is 'APP' length equal to 3?

I expect query will return an empty result if test if false, otherwise run the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

I hope `CASE` expression will help in this case, can you try the query below:

```
select distinct CASE WHEN length(ss.schemaname) = 3 THEN ss.schemaname ELSE '' END AS SCHEMANAME
from sys.sysschemas ss 
fetch next 1 row only;
```

Comment: I really need select * from tmpuser.friends to run only if length of 'APP' is 3. Otherwise return nothing.